# XML Xpath - select where element = multiple values

Tags: xml, xpath, multiple-conditions

Fairly straightforward question, but seems pretty hard to find what I want through search, here or Google.

Most people ask how you can select a node/ element with multiple conditions.

Like `URL/books[title="Harry Potter" and author="JKRowling"]`

I want to know if there's a way to shorten that syntax if you have multiple possibilities for one attribute.

In other words

```
URL/books[price=1 or price=2 or price=3 or price=8 or price=15]
```

Is there a way to shorten that syntax?

Like `URL/books[price=1,2,3]` or `[price in (1,2,3)]` ---- obviously these are wrong, but would make things easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPath 2.0 would allow

```
URL/books[price=(1,2,3)]
```

The `=` operator (and also `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=`) in XPath has an implicit existential quantifier when either or both of its operands are sequences - `X = Y` is true if *any* member of the sequence `X` is equal to *any* member of the sequence `Y`.  Note that this means that `X != Y` is not necessarily the same as `not(X = Y)` - the former means there is *some* pair of X and Y values that are not equal (and there might also be other pairs that are equal), the latter means that there are *no* equal pairs at all.

However XPath 1.0 doesn't support sequences of atomic values like this, its only multi-valued data type is the *node set*.  If you could somehow inject a variable with the list of values as XML, e.g.

```
<prices>
  <price>1</price>
  <price>2</price>
  <price>3</price>
</prices>
```

then you could say

```
URL/books[price = $var/prices/price]
```

but that (a) depends on whether and how your XPath engine supports variable bindings and (b) is probably less clear than just enumerating `price = 1 or price = 2 ...` anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm actually using the newest version I'm sure  - so your first line makes sense - I just didn't know the syntax as it doesn't seem to appear in the searches I've conducted. i'd upvote you but I guess I don't have the 15 rep yet

Comment: @JohnBabson you don't yet have the rep to upvote but you can _accept_ the answer if you think it solved your problem.  You do this by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer.